# Exclude columns from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm writing a Simple API in Ruby on Rails, I want to be able to automatically hide columns from being visible for example if I wanted to select Users I never want to share passwords, salt or any other personal information.

In Laravel you can use a protected variable '$guarded' and I was wondering if this is possible in Rails?

Edit: I'm using JSON to display the data.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a serialiser where you specify exactly what columns you want to go in the response.

I think https://github.com/rails/jbuilder is the default now but there are others such as:

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Assuming your api is a JSON api.

Also you can use `as_json` like so.

```
def show
  @resource.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an API endpoint you can do something like this:
In your controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]).to_api_json
```

And in your user class return what you want in a hash:

```
def to_api_json
  { "id": id, "email": email } # add whatever attributes you want to this hash
end
```

You can tweak depending on what format of data you want to return, but this is the basic idea.